# Free theorems and parametricity

Tags: math, haskell, types, functional-programming, logic

I've found this [webapp](http://www-ps.iai.uni-bonn.de/cgi-bin/free-theorems-webui.cgi) which lets you generate a free theorem for a given type.

The generated theorems quantify over types and relations on these types. These theorems (formulas) are theorems of which theory/logical system? How does this system relate to the equational theory of the language?

Comment: You might want to browse [this stuff](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/parametricity.html) if you haven't already.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question seems [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for Stack Overflow. It might be better suited for our sister site, http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

See the paper that introduced it all.

http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/wadler.pdf

[image]